# Custom view displaying image tiles

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view, android-custom-view

I need a solution to display large images without reducing the quality of said image. The idea I had was to split the image into tiles which would give me sort of a table. Multiple rows and columns of images.

I want to create a custom view where I would build an internal table where each cell would be of fixed size and carry the name of the image (tile) it needs to display. This way I would have to load only a portion of original image onto the scene and load other images from disk as user swipes.

I don't need the work done for me just general information how to tackle this problem or a link to a resource.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this project on github. It is using subsampling technique

https://github.com/davemorrissey/subsampling-scale-image-view

Comment: Well it does not really use tiles. It loads the image with lower quality one which allows it to find into memory and than as you zoom in loads only visible regions. I was hoping for a true tile approach as mentioned.